# What affects the max_connections_per_hour value in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been writing a CMS for my website and I'm hosting it on Awardspace, which has a limit of `max_connections_per_hour` of 1500.
 So, naturally I thought this was the amount of connections you make to the database. I create a new PDO object at the start of my PHP file and I close it at the end. So I only make 1 connection per page. However, I still keep exceeding the `max_connections_per_hour` value.
This has me puzzled, since there is no way I'm loading over 1500 pages in an hour.

I do, however, make 22 queries per page. So maybe that is what is affecting the `max_connections_per_hour` value? Even then, I still think it is weird that I'm exceeding 1500.

Is there any MySQL command I can execute that shows the amount of connections I've already made this hour? I already know about `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS`, but the limit is on a per user basis, so if I use `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` it shows me the connections all users have made.

Does anyone have an explanation for why this could be happening?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: My database class:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/configuration.php');

class Database {

    private $dbh;
    public $queryCount = 0;

    function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DATABASE_HOST . ';dbname=' . DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    function executeQuery($query, $parameters = array()) {
        try {
            $statement = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
            $statement->execute($parameters);
            $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $result = $statement->fetchAll();
            $this->queryCount += 1;
            return $result;
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    function close() {
        $this->dbh = NULL;
    }
}
```

And I use:

```
$database = new Database();
```

at the top of the page, and

```
$database->close();
```

at the bottom.

To execute queries I use the appropriate function in between.

Comment: those 22 queries should be shareing one connection unless your doing something  crazy.

Comment: Well I have a database class, which creates a connection on construction and then I use a function in that class to execute queries using that connection, so if I'm not mistaken that should be the correct method, right?

Comment: show your code for connection @Qub1 maybe you dont do it write

Comment: @meda Edited my question with the database class

Comment: do you use phpmyadmin?

Comment: @michael Yes I do. I use it to manage certain CMS related entries

Comment: There are very good statistics available in phpmyadmin. In the upper bar, click on "Server->localhost" then below on "status" and then you have all connections made, if you click on "Query statistics" you also get a complete overview of what's happening

Comment: @michael Yeah but I'm on a shared server so it shows all the queries everyone has done which are about 3 million so far. I can't accurately monitor my own usage there, only global usage.

Comment: Why don't you use a logging infrastructure that logs every constructor call of your `Database` class (equivalent with creating a connection), with the caller and timestamp? Then you can check that file an use it as the base for your detailed analysis...

Comment: @ZombieHunter Hmm, that's a good idea, I'll try that and see what I find

Comment: @ZombieHunter Okay, I've tried that and found there was a function which was recreating the database object 7 times. So, doing the math, that means that every page made 7 connections, so that would still amount to 214 pages to load before I would reach the limit of 1500. I'm going to investigate some more and see if I can get to the bottom of this.

Comment: @Qub1: I usually use a Singleton Pattern for my `MySQLConnection` class. This way every request uses at most one real connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening a connection is an expensive operation, you are opening one on each page since your force it to close.

You should be checking if the connection is null first before creating a new one.

And also you should not close it manually.

Try the singleton approach when creating the connection:

**Conn.php**

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/configuration.php');

class Conn{
    protected static $db;

    private function __construct() {
        try {
            self::$db = new PDO(
                    'mysql:host=' . DATABASE_HOST . ';dbname=' . DATABASE_NAME, 
                    DATABASE_USERNAME, 
                    DATABASE_PASSWORD, 
                    array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)
               );

            self::$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static function getConnection() {
        if (!self::$db) {
            new Conn();
        }
        return self::$db;
    }

}
?>
```

**Database.php**

```
<?php
require_once('Conn.php');

class Database{

    static $dbh;
    static $queryCount = 0;

    public function __construct() {
         self::$dbh = Conn::getConnection();
        var_dump(self::$dbh);
    }

    public static function executeQuery($query, $parameters = array()) {
        try {
            $statement = self::$dbh->prepare($query);
            $statement->execute($parameters);
            $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $result = $statement->fetchAll();
            self::$queryCount += 1;
            return $result;
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
include 'Database.php';
$db = new Database();
$data = $db->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM example ');
var_dump($data);
```